# RETURNING parameter in SELECT (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, sql-returning

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '423423432r32' RETURNING name
```

Does the `RETURNING` clause exist in `SELECT`, and if it doesn't, what can I use instead of to get the same result?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you looking for: `select u.*, name from users u where u.user_id = ...`?

Comment: **[XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**

Comment: "To get the same result"... What "result" are you looking for.

Comment: ["andrew","vasya"] etc ....only data from one table

Comment: Why do you want to use `RETURNING` here? A `SELECT` already returns, why an extra return?

Comment: because I do not need all fields from the table - only which I need

Comment: Then `SELECT the_field_you_want`. `*` is just a placeholder that means "all columns".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments and from what I can understand from your question what you want is just the result of the query

`SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = '423423432r32'`

the return statement is more used for things like

`insert into table1 (foo, bar, baz)
values (X, Y, Z) 
returning *`

so that you can see the updated or inserted rows,

more info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/dml-returning.html)